# Migrate from Marketo to CRM

Tags: integration, dynamics-crm-2013, marketo

Im trying to use the Marketo Connector (From ScribeOnline) to make a integration between Marketo and CRM.

I need to integrate Marketo.Programs but I don't see it in the entities that the connector provide me. 
Im brand new with Marketo and I dont really know how the relations are in there, so I don't know if this is unsupported or if Marketo.Programs have another name. I look the Scribe forums but I havent found anything.

Anyone who knows about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution is to pull the Marketo program data directly from the Marketo API using the [getMObjects SOAP API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/soap/getmobjects/). Specify "Program" as the "Type" field name in your request.